# EF Core understanding migrations

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I encountered some weird behaviour with EF Core 3.1 that made me wondering what is actually happening. So hopefully someone can explain this to me in all fine details.

**Scenario**

Let's say you have two projects. Project A (main) and project B (side-project). For both projects you can add/remove migrations, as project A is set-up to get all pending migrations from project B on start-up and execute them.

When executing`dotnet ef migrations add Test -c AppDbContext -o DbContexts/Migrations/AppDb` on project A and after completion (BEFORE even applying it to the DB) execute `dotnet ef migrations remove -c AppDbContext`, everything works as expected and the migration gets removed.

For project B on the otherhand after succesfully executing the `add` command, the moment that I try to execute the `remove` command (also BEFORE even applying it to the DB), I get the following error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related
> or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
> that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
> Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

So I took the error message as an advice and started to follow [this guide](https://medium.com/@nishancw/how-to-enable-remote-connections-to-sql-server-dc5b6c812b5) to allow remote access to the database. After the guide, the `remove` command on project B was also successfully executed.

But now I am wondering... Why wasn't EF Core connecting to the (LOCAL) DB before I followed the guide and DID it work on project A, but not on B....?

**EDIT**

After some more research, I discovered the specific action from the guide that helped me to resolve the error that I got. It was to set the TCP Port to 1433 in the Sql Server Configuration Manager. Apparently this field was empty... But it leaves me with 1 question.

Why did the `add` command DID work without a port specified and was only the `remove` command complaining about the connection?

**EDIT2**

And yet another new finding, when adding the following method to the `AppDbContext` class:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
{
    options.UseSqlServer("foo");
    base.OnConfiguring(options);
}
```

The `add` command works fine, but the `remove` command complains about the incorrect format of the connectionstring

> System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

So we can conclude from this that the `add` command DOESN'T require a valid connectionstring (as it does nothing with the DB), while the `remove` command DOES require a valid connectionstring... but why??? It does nothing with the DB, right?

Comment: Are you sure that you had correct con string written on project B ?

Comment: @AVTUNEY , I wish that was the issue. But I checked that like 10 times and it was exactly the same connectionstring as with the `add` command.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to my own question, here an explanation on how the `add` and `remove` migrations work.

The `add` migration functionality DOES require a valid string as the connectionstring in the context, but it DOESN'T need to be a correct connectionstring, as EF Core is not realy connecting to the DB.

For the `remove` migration functionality, you DO require a correct connectionstring, as EF Core makes a connection to the DB to compare the local list of migrations with the `_EFMigrationsHistory` table to check if there are any migrations that has not been applied to the DB. Because the `remove` functionality can only remove PENDING migrations. So not any migrations that have already been applied to the DB.